# From GeoPandas df column containing list of tuple coordinates to a column containing LineString

Tags: python, dataframe, geopandas, shapely

I have a GeoPandas df:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'oof'], 'geometry': [[(5.239672304278279, 43.449400744605434), (5.291017601291771, 43.40657292095388)], [(5.27346289130589, 43.418074031107516), (4.935465352479518, 43.44997495014662)], [(4.935465352479518, 43.44997495014662), (5.64570049516335, 43.367506660731095)]]})
```

which looks like:

```
   name   geometry
0   foo    [(5.239672304278279, 43.449400744605434), (5.2...
1   bar    [(5.27346289130589, 43.418074031107516), (4.93...
2   oof    [(4.935465352479518, 43.44997495014662), (5.64...
```

How do I transform the coordinate column into LineString (regardless of how many points are in the list of tuples)?
E.g.:

```
   name   geometry
0   foo    LINESTRING (5.239672304278279 43.449400744605434, 5.2...
1   bar    LINESTRING (5.27346289130589 43.418074031107516, 4.93...
2   oof    LINESTRING (4.935465352479518 43.44997495014662, 5.64...
```

Edit:
I've tried (see Prateek's answer):

```
geo_df['geometry']=geo_df['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x))
```

as well as:

```
geo_list = [LineString(x) for i in geo_df['geometry'].tolist()]
geo_df['geometry'] = geo_list
```

Both return the following error:

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapely/speedups/_speedups.pyx in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '**array_interface**'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
17 geo_df['geometry'] = tuple_list
18
---> 19 geo_df['geometry'] = geo_df['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x))
20
21

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
4198             else:
4199                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4200                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
4201
4202         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

in (x)
17 geo_df['geometry'] = tuple_list
18
---> 19 geo_df['geometry'] = geo_df['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x))
20
21

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapely/geometry/linestring.py in **init**(self, coordinates)
46         BaseGeometry.**init**(self)
47         if coordinates is not None:
---> 48             self._set_coords(coordinates)
49
50     @property

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapely/geometry/linestring.py in _set_coords(self, coordinates)
95     def _set_coords(self, coordinates):
96         self.empty()
---> 97         ret = geos_linestring_from_py(coordinates)
98         if ret is not None:
99             self._geom, self._ndim = ret

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapely/speedups/_speedups.pyx in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py()

AssertionError:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be simple.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'oof'], 'geometry': [[(5.239672304278279, 43.449400744605434), (5.291017601291771, 43.40657292095388)], [(5.27346289130589, 43.418074031107516), (4.935465352479518, 43.44997495014662)], [(4.935465352479518, 43.44997495014662), (5.64570049516335, 43.367506660731095)]]})

geo_df['geometry']=geo_df['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x))
```